# Deleting records from one table joined onto another table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have two tables one with 212,000 records (deprecated records) and the other with 10,500,000 records

I would like to join the two tables on id and version_number fields as both tables have these fields. I was hoping that from the joined table that the matched records (from the joined tables) could be deleted i.e all of the 212,000 records get deleted from the 10,500,000

I was wondering what the best approach would be for this using Oracle SQL?  I have seen
example where inner join has been used using a single field and a delete statement has been used to delete table1 from table 2 but not seen one with two fields used (in the join).

Would it make sense to use an outer join before deleting the records? I was thinking this may help me track what has been deleted if possible

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use `OUTER JOIN` except for the check how many rows will resp. will *not* be deleted.

An example of such query see below (I use generated test data provided at the end of the answer)

```
with del as (
select delta.id, delta.version,
decode(big.id,null,0,1) is_deleted
from delta
left outer join big 
on delta.id = big.id and delta.version = big.version
)
select is_deleted, count(*) cnt, max(id||'.'||version) eg_id_vers
from del
group by is_deleted;

IS_DELETED        CNT  EG_ID_VERS                                                                   
---------- ---------- ----------
         1      20000 99995.0   
         0         20 100100.0
```

With your data size you should use a `HASH JOIN` with `full table scan` on both tables to get acceptable performance.

There are basically two options how to do the `DELETE`

**Updatable Join View**

Note that in this case your small table *must have an unique index on* `ID, VERSION` (or a primary key)

```
create unique index delta_idx on delta(id,version);
```

Contrary the BIG table should *not have such constraint*. This is important, because it clearly indicates that you BIG table is the only one *key preserving table* in the join view.

Simple put a join to the small table *can't duplicate rows* from the big table  due to the *unique contraint*

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-C37E704C-AF40-42DA-85ED-372A62A74E58) more information about **Updating a Join Views**

```
delete from 
(
select delta.id, delta.version, big.id big_id, big.version
from big 
join delta 
on delta.id = big.id and delta.version = big.version
)
```

The `delete` above removes rows from the `BIG` table because this is the only *key preserving table* (see the discussion above)

This DML leads to a `HASH JOIN`

**Delete with EXISTS**

If your small table has no primary key (i.e. it can contain duplicated rows with same `ID and VERSION`) you must *fallback* to the solution proposed in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59911522/4808122).

```
DELETE FROM big 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null
                  FROM delta
                  WHERE delta.id = big.id and delta.version = big.version
                 )
```

No indexes are required and you should expect an execution plan with `HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI`, which means that both approaches are not realy different.

**Sample Data for Test**

```
create table big as
select 
trunc(rownum/10) id, mod(rownum,10) version,
lpad('x',10,'Y') pad
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

/* the DELTA table has 50 times less rows,
allow some rows out of range of the BIG table - those rows will not be deleted **/
drop table delta;
create table delta as
select 
trunc(rownum*50/10) id, mod(rownum*50,10) version
from dual connect by level <= 1001000/50;

create unique index delta_idx on delta(id,version);
```

Comment: Thanks Marmite Bomber for the excellent answer and explanation!  I'll try both approaches

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach just uses `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM bigtable bt
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM littletable lt
                  WHERE bt.? = lt.?
                 );
```

You want an index on `littletable` for the keys used for the correlation clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I was wondering in the select clause if the bt.? - lt.? represents the common fields between the two tables i.e the id and version number fields? or would I need to make explicit i.e WHERE bt.id  = lt.id and bt.versionnumber = lt.versionnumber ?  Also does the EXISTS give better performance than other approaches?

Comment: @daveb . . . Your question is not clear on how the tables are related.  If you want an answer specific to your particular data, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you need.