# DELETE FROM two tables on a join in oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to delete related rows from two tables. There might or might not be a foreign key, involved. So to be sure, I don't want to rely on foreign keys and their `CASCADE ON DELETE`. Is the following syntax possible in Oracle?

```
DELETE orders o, order_items i WHERE o.order id = i.order id;
```

Comment: You may delete from an *updatable join view*, but you will delete rows from only one table. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911501/deleting-records-from-one-table-joined-onto-another-table-sql/59912961#59912961) related answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. `Delete`, in Oracle, affects only one table, which means that you'll have to use two statements.